# htmx: Trigger based on all radio buttons in a form

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to trigger ht-get of a form based on the change of any of the radio buttons in the form without the user having to hit the submit button. Therefore, I'm trying to use the hx-trigger attribute on the form with the from:find feature, but I keep getting an htmx:syntax:error in the console and no triggering.

`<form action="/cvss/calc" method="get" id="cvss-calc" novalidate hx-get="/cvss/calc/cvss_details_html" hx-trigger="from:find form#cvss-calc .btn-check">`

All the radio buttons have the btn-check class defined on them. I've also tried `from:find .btn-check` but that doesn't work either.

What would be the proper format for doing this?

UPDATE: I figured it out, I was apparently trying to be too fancy. I changed the hx-trigger to be just "change" and it works wonderfully since the form only has radio boxes.

It would  still be nice, though, to know how to listen for change signals from only specific sets of inputs.

Comment: the correct syntaxt in your case is `hx-trigger="change from:find .btn-check"`. However, the htmx contains bugs. Read this [solution](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/569#issuecomment-906918979). Please note that the `form:find` will return a single element, if you need multiple elements you will need to modify the `querySelectorAllExt` function to return a set of elements. You will need to replace the line `return [find(elt, selector.substr(5))];` with `return findAll(elt, selector.substr(5));`